# How to extract submatrix from a tensor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to extract first 2 columns of a tensor.

For example, 
consider this tensor

```
[[0, 1, -1, -2, -3],

 [1, 0, -8, -2, -3]]
```

The output should be

```
[[0,1],
[1,0]]
```

I played with tf.unstack() but could not succeed completely.

Comment: what kind of object is that tensor? A `list`? You could do `res = [x[:2] for x in tensor]`

Comment: It's a tensorflow variable.
tf.Variable(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tf.slice()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice)

```
tf.slice(varTensor, [0, 0], [2, 2]);
```

You can test it

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.Session().run(tf.slice([[0,1,-1,-2,-3],[1,0,-9, -2, -3]], [0, 0], [2,2]))
```

Comment: Thanks.
Can tf.slice(varTensor,[0, 0], [-1, 2]) be  applied when number of rows dynamic?

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more readable than Kris Roofe's solution, using tensorflow's python slicing operator:

```
tensor[:,0:2]
```

If you are familiar with python's standard slicing notation, you already know how to use tensorflow's.